# Can't import modules in python after installing them with pip

Tags: python, pip

I am trying to use the `pyserial` module in my python project, so i installed it with `pip install pyserial`. After doing that, I did `import pyserial` in my python interpreter and it gave me this error:

[image: error]

Pyserial appears in my `pip list` list, and when i do `pip show pyserial` it gives this result:

[image: pip list]

Comment: Are you sure you're importing it within the same environment?

Comment: Try `pip3 install pyserial`. Issue could be multi python version

Comment: Also try `import sys; print(sys.path)` to make sure Python is looking in the correct `site-packages` directory.

Comment: Please post code and error messages as code-formatted text, not images.

Comment: None of these solutions worked, but @12944qwerty, what do you mean?

Comment: @zacharycohen you might be installing the packages in a different environment than what you're in.

Comment: Also, are you using PyCharm? (Assuming from the answer you had)

Answer (score 3):

I think you're using a wrong import statement, `import pyserial` will give you and should give you the above error .

The correct import statement is `import serial`, so try this instead.

Always it's a good thing to read the documentation, you can read more about pyserial on the docs [here](https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/shortintro.html)

Comment: I did what you said, however it gave the same result.

Comment: you didn't specify that you're using Pycharm, however i noticed the wrong import statement. Anyway glad you got along with that by typing import serial and then installed it correctly .. Also there is another answer explaining how to install packages when working with Pycharm .. finally could you please choose an answer n mark it as accepted . so the question will be marked as answered

Answer (score 2):

Pycharm has a different way to install packages. You shouldn't install them via `pip`. I'm not sure why `pip` doesn't always install packages properly is though.

Instead, you can install it by opening the tool page in the main menu. This is available for PyCharm 2021.1 and later.

```
View -> Tool Windows -> Python Packages -> Search
```

You can also open the project interpreter to install packages.

```
Settings (CTRL+ALT+S) -> Project_Name -> Python Interpreter -> + (symbol at bottom) -> Search
```

See this [article](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/installing-uninstalling-and-upgrading-packages.html) for a more complete tutorial.

Comment: Your answer solved my issue. Only took me 2 hours to try and figure out why I wasn't able to install the package. Apparently in PyCharm, View -> Tool Windows -> Python Packages -> Search, I had install it manually even after importing it using pip install command. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this problem in PyCharm by typing `import serial` and it gave me an option to auto-install it. I took that option, and it worked.